# sudo service networking start doesn't work

Tags: networking, dns, upstart, services

I just configured dns-nameservers in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

To make it take effect instantly, I typed `sudo service networking stop`, the desktop seems to kill some processes, anyway the UI is down...

Then I switch to `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and type `sudo service networking start`.
It prompts that `networking stop/waiting`.
I've tried several times and can't figure out what's the reason. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands to start, stop and restart network manager are

```
sudo service network-manager stop

sudo service network-manager start

sudo service network-manager restart
```

You set the dns-nameservers in network manager and not /etc/network/interfaces unless you are not using network manger because network manger will overwrite what is in /etc/network/interfaces.